# Is there any way to combine these scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to learn jQuery, but I can't figure out how to make one div slide down separately from the others, without making a separate script for each div. Whenever I try to make it into one script, the divs do the same slide at the same time.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").Toggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip2").click(function(){
    $("#pane2").Toggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style>
#panel, #flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
 padding: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>


<div id="flip1">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>


<div id="flip2">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="pane2">Hello world!</div>

</body>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use slideToggle()

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I copied the wrong code. Thank you though.

Comment: use classnames instead of ID's https://jsfiddle.net/njz2ad9u/

Comment: use DaniP's solution except use slideToggle() in place of slideUp('slow');

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton (Engineer @ Google)](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: @C.Schulz If you feel one answer helped you the most, you can click the gray checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `this` value inside the callback. First, change your `id="flip#"` to `class="flip"` and `id="panel#"` to `class="panel"`. Then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.panel').slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

This will take the clicked element’s `next` sibling, then slide it up.

Comment: And if you absolutely want to keep your ID attributes, then `$("#flip, #flip1, #flip2").click(function(){`

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is fragile code, if the dom changes the javascript fails to work correctly.

Comment: @ErikPhilips How can I fix it then?

Comment: @JF take a look at [user2181397's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40363063/209259).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. In simplest way you can remove the multiple `document.ready` & put all the code inside one `document.ready`.

Beside that you can create a single class and add an attribute `data-item` & pass the id of the div you want to slide up.

Inside `click` function use `$(this)` to point the jquery object.

Hope this snippet will be useful

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickItem").click(function() {
        var getItem =$(this).attr('data-item')
      $("#"+getItem).slideUp("slow");
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="flip"  class="clickItem" data-item="panel">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip1"  class="clickItem" data-item="panel1">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip2"class="clickItem" data-item="pane2" >Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="pane2">Hello world!</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/f2e9vnwh/)

Comment: My personal take is that instead of `data-item` it should be named `data-target` and instead of prefixing a hard coded value the target contains the *full* selector e.g. `data-target='#pane2'`.  This means you can reuse it to close multiple items if you targeted a class instead of an Id.

Comment: Agree with you. That is a better way

Comment: Oh and use `.data()` instead of `attr()`, jquery already has an easy way to read the [data attributes](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Answer (score 0):

To trim down the code, use classes instead of ID's like so:

```
<div class="flip">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>

<div class="flip">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Then, in your script (one script) just hide all of the panels when the page loads using `hide()` and listen for the `.flip` class to be clicked. When it is, initiate `slideToggle()` on the `next()` element.

```
$(".panel").hide();

$(".flip").click(function() {

  $(this).next().slideToggle();

});
```

***DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yupobomuje/edit?html,js,output***

Comment: This is fragile code, if the dom changes the javascript fails to work correctly.

Comment: @ErikPhilips How would you write it to account for DOM changes?

Comment: take a look at [user2181397's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40363063/209259).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Ah, I think I see what you mean. You referring to the $(this).next()? Yup. I was assuming that it would always be in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

My answer is really just an update to [user2181397's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363063/209259):

html:

```
<div id="flip" class="js-slide-up" data-target="#panel">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip1" class="js-slide-up" data-target="#panel1">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip2" class="js-slide-up" data-target="#pane2" >Click to slide up     panel</div>
<div id="pane2">Hello world!</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-slide-up").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('target')
    $(selector).slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

This is pretty cool because these all work:

```
<div class="js-slide-up" data-target="#panel,#panel1">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="panel1">Hello world!</div>

<div class="js-slide-up" data-target=".panel">Click to slide up panel</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```